# Why are there no cycles in this "1234-graph" on the permutations

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

Fix $n\in\mathbb N$, and consider the following directed graph whose vertices are the permutations of length $n$:

For a permutation $p=[p_1,..., p_j, ..., p_k, .., .p_n]$ with if $p_j+j=k$, then there is an edge from $p$ to $[p_1, ..., p_k, ..., p_j, ..., p_n]$. In words: In the list that is the permutation, a number $x$ can swap its position with the number $x$ places to its right.

For example, for n=6 there are edges from `123456` to `213456`, to `143256`, and to `126453`.

The whole 1234-graph¹ looks like this for n=3:

```
123 → 213 → 312 → 321
       ↓     ↑
      231 → 132
```

<sub>¹) I'll name it 1234-graph, since it is really nice for n=4, and planar too. In fact, it is just the right degree of difficult to draw in the plane that it makes a nice [half-an-hour puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98436/draw-this-planar-graph).</sub>

It appears that, regardless of $n$, this graph has no cycles; and it sure feels like there *should* be a relatively simple reason, for example a half-ordering / monovariant based on the contents. Or an inductive proof reducing the question to the smaller graph on permutations of length $n-1$. **Why are there no cycles?**

Comment: @PaulHudford I don't see how, at a glance. If one of the "middle" edges in the graph for n=3 was reversed, it would create a cycle, but not break symmetry.

Comment: There is a symmetry (where the edge 1234→2134 corresponds to the edge 4312→4321: "reverse the permutations, reverse the edges". Also, the graph $G_n$ obviously contains copies of $G_{n-1}$ as subgraphs.

Comment: yep sorry, I deleted my comment after I noted my error.

Comment: Another symmetry is, I believe, with the inverse permutations.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for n=5, this is a cycle:

$13254→14253→14352→41352→21354→23154→13254$

And copies of this cycle appear in all graphs for larger $n$.

Comment: I've found this by thinking about the positions and values tha could possibly be moved in a cycle. I now remember finding a cycle for n=5 some years ago, following this exact thought.

Comment: That was interesting. I started trying to find one but I stoped quickly doing something else. This leads to some more question now : is this unique for $n=5$ ? It trivially induces a cycle for any $n$, but can we found other ? Could we derive a methodology to find one, ideally involving all numbers (not just this cycle with other numbers appended in the end)?

Comment: Could you detailed your methodology (in the post) ?

Comment: @PaulHudford oh, no methocology at all. I knew that there were no cycles when n=4; (and no cycles involving just three indices). I was looking to prove the same for n=5 (and higher), and fiddling with the numbers; summing the $j+p_j=k$ equation for several stept. But really, using a pencil and trying.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal of the graph is always
$$  (n \ n-1 \ n-2 \ \dots \ 3 \ 2 \ 1)  $$
as this is the only permutation in which no symbol can be swapped.

There is no edge whose reverse is already in the graph.  That is, there are no bidirectional edges.  Such a pair of directed edges would require that the two swapped symbols be the same, which cannot happen, so there is at most one directed edge between any two permutations.

A trail in the graph is a sequence of [shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) moves (of differing gap), eventually pushing small symbols to the right and large symbols to the left.  Consider the graph of a permutation.  (The graph of the points $(i,p_i)$ with line segments drawn between points with successive $i$s.)  A line of slope $-1$ corresponds to the final state, the permutation displayed above.  Any position in the permutation whose point is on or above that line contains a number too big to swap to its right.  Any position whose point is below that line can swap to the right -- any such swap reduces the area of the graph above the line.  That area strictly monotonically decreases along any trail in the graph, so there can be no cycles in the graph.

Comment: I'll have to think about this, but it doesn't seem to be strictly right: 42531→43521 does reduce that area "above 54321" from 3 to 2, but 43521→13524 *increases* that area from 2 to 5.